# Subquery works by itself, not in update statement

Tags: sql, subquery

Here is the statement. The subquery returns the correct values on its own, but in the update statement it says it returns more than one value.

```
update MasterList
set SSI_Rep =    (select [SS Rep] from RepAssign join 
                  MasterList on  MasterList.ST = RepAssign.State
                  and MasterList.RSM = RepAssign.RSM )
```

Comment: When you say the subquery "returns the correct values" do you mean "returns the correct value" (singular). If the subquery returns more than one row, then your statement would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE
    MasterList
SET
    SSI_Rep = RepAssign.[SS Rep]
from
    MasterList
join
    RepAssign
on
    MasterList.ST = RepAssign.State
and MasterList.RSM = RepAssign.RSM
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, the query is attempting to update all rows in Masterlist with the same value for SSI_Rep.  So the error message is correctly stating that you're trying to update a row value with many values.   I'm betting that that's not what you want to do and that you want to be doing an UPDATE FROM query:

```
UPDATE MasterList
SET SSI_Rep = RepAssign.[SS Rep]
FROM MasterList
JOIN RepAssign
ON MasterList.ST = RepAssign.State
AND MasterList.RSM = RepAssign.RSM
```